# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at lt (d3.v5.min.js:2)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the billboard.js library, and it's working on one page, but when I create another page, it doesn't work.

I don't now why I must use the same code.

But I have an error in d3.v5.min.js lib.

The error is:

```
d3.v5.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at lt (d3.v5.min.js:2)
at Rt.style (d3.v5.min.js:2)
at ChartInternal.getParentHeight (size.js:126)
at ChartInternal.getCurrentHeight (size.js:16)
at ChartInternal.updateSizes (ChartInternal.js:431)
at ChartInternal.initWithData (ChartInternal.js:250)
at ChartInternal.init (ChartInternal.js:82)
at new Chart (Chart.js:58)
at Object.generate (core.js:51)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (plugin.js:236)
```

Comment: Can you please share your piece where you are using or initializing D3 ? It usually happens when you are applying something on an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: We need more code to be able to help you.Post the code in which you call the function that throws the error

Comment: here the HTML code

 <div id="MultilneTitle3"></div>
and here the js code 
var chart3 = bb.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
 ["data1", 40],
 ["data2", 35],
 ["data3", 20],
 ["data4", 5]
    ],
    type: "donut"
  },
  donut: {
    title: "4.5"
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  },
  bindto: "#MultilneTitle3"
});

Comment: @AsmaaA.Al-Baik, Is your script placed after your html code here?

Comment: @AsmaaA.Al-Baik Please share complete code in the question description.

Comment: @YousafHassan no I didn't,
 I placed it in separate js file and it's work will in page and it didn't work in another page

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.